# Error during rendering of region Application Express - Sign In

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I recently installed Oracle APEX and now trying to access APEX through

http://localhost:8080/.

When I access the page, I encounter this error. I am using Oracle Database 11g R2 and Apex Ver 18.1, I installed Oracle Data Services. When i did following step It shows me rendering error. I run following script to resolve image problem

```
reset_image_prefix.sql
Enter the Application Express image prefix [/i/] :/i/
```

my **ord_params.properties** file have following entry

```
**standalone.static.images=D\:\\ords.18.1.1.95.1251\\images**
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know that running `@apxldimg` script helps in such a situation. Did you try it? As a parameter, it expects directory that contains the `\apex` directory. In the following example, full path to `\apex` directory is `C:\5_apex_instalacija\apex4\apex`.

It is a copy/paste from my Apex 4.x installation notes (didn't run it right now):

```
SQL> @apxldimg C:\5_apex_instalacija\apex4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

old   1: create directory APEX_IMAGES as '&1/apex/images'
new   1: create directory APEX_IMAGES as 'C:\5_apex_instalacija\apex4/apex/images'
```